# Why @Query annotation not working to SpringBoot Version 2.7.4 CouchbaseRepository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I Upgraded Project to SpringBoot Version 2.2.0.RELEASE to 2.7.4.This is the example Repository Interface.

```
import com.flyaero.aeromasterapiservice.data.AddLanguageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.N1qlPrimaryIndexed;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
public interface LanguageRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<AddLanguageRequest, String> {

    Optional<AddLanguageRequest> findById(String id);

    AddLanguageRequest save(AddLanguageRequest entity);

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE modelName = 'AddLanguageRequest' AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
    List<AddLanguageRequest> findAll();
}
```

After Change the **SpringBoot version to 2.7.4** cannot use CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository.We can use only **CouchbaseRepository**. Problem is **@Query is not supporting**.

```
import com.flyaero.aeromasterapiservice.data.AddLanguageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.N1qlPrimaryIndexed;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.Query;
//import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
public interface LanguageRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<AddLanguageRequest, String> {

    Optional<AddLanguageRequest> findById(String id);

    AddLanguageRequest save(AddLanguageRequest entity);
    
    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE modelName = 'AddLanguageRequest' AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
    List<AddLanguageRequest> findAll();
}
```

**What would be the best possible options?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Repositories & Queries**

***org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.Query became org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.Query***

More details available in latest Spring Data Couchbase - Reference Documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.multibucket